# What is the cost of Multiattack on Unarmed Attacks?

Tags: unarmed-combat, mutants-and-masterminds-3e, multiattack

It may be a newbie question but nontheless...
How much does the Multiattack Extra cost on Unarmed Strikes, if it is even possible?
I have a Unarmed Attack based character, with the current strength of 3, fighting of 3, and a bonus Close Combat: Unarmed Attacks of 4. My power level is 6. I have no combat powers, nor advantages (Main theme being an unhittable, hit-n'-run teleporter with low damage but high versatility).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## You apply the cost of your Multiattack to your Strength damage.

If you want to apply a modifier like Multiattack to a Strength-based Damage effect, you buy Multiattack for the Strength modifier as well as any additional Damage that's placed on top of it.

For your example character, you have a Strength of 3, so buying Multiattack for it would cost 3 points.

Also, as a side note, you should generally buy your attacks up to the limits set by your Power Level; at the moment, you've got an attack roll of +7 but only a damage of 3. You could plausibly buy some Brass Knuckles or Gauntlets that give you Strength-based Damage 1 as Equipment, and you might be able to increase their damage further by making them heavier, spikier, or adding something like electrical shocks to them; a Katar (also known as a punch-dagger) is listed as doing Strength-based Damage 2 (Penetrating 1).

If you did this, applying the Multiattack effect would also require you to buy it for your weapon damage as well; if you bought a Katar, you'd have to pay 3 Equipment Points for the Katar, and then 5 points for the Multiattack power.

Comment: The Damage power has a note about modifiers and Strength, in the Strength and Damage section. Quoting that would improve your answer.

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on [nick012000's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/160451/10867), the book specifically addresses [applying Extras to Strength damage](https://www.d20herosrd.com/6-powers/effects/effect-descriptions/damage-attack/#TOC-STRENGTH-AND-DAMAGE):

> Strength provides a “built-in” Damage effect: the ability to hit things! You can apply effect modifiers to the damage your Strength inflicts, making it Penetrating or even an Area effect! You can also have **Alternate Effects** for your Strength Damage; see the Alternate Effect modifier for details. Like other Damage effects, a character’s Strength Damage is close range and instant duration by default.

Unlike most extras, the game does seem to allow such Extras to be conditional, so if you put *Area (Burst)* on your Strength Damage, you get to choose whether to apply it. If you want to be strict, you can require 1 PP AEs for each case of whether the Extra is added or not to bring this in line with other power effects.

One last thing from nick012000's answer, adding weapon damage to your character is fine (although always up to the GM whether, say, Superman gets a chance to do more damage if he picks up a knife). Theoretically, Equipment and Powers don't mix, but most GMs will allow a bit of overlap, although the combination still can't break PL, and it does mean that you'll be under PL without the weapon.